# In PhpStorm :: tab rows reorder on click & jump on drag&drop

Tags: layout, tabs, split, phpstorm

Handling the tabs right now is crazy !!

Often I use a split layout / workspace. Mostly I split vertically.
After a short time I have 10 tabs left, 10 tabs right

1. If I try to reorder a tab by dragging it, the tabs beneath it (the place I'd like to drop the tab) jump around and flicker.
2. If I click a tab (of a row) all rows reorder... what the * ? How to keep an overview like this.
3. I can't drag from one view to the other.

So my associated questions would be...

About 1. Am I doing something wrong ?
About 2. Are there some settings to disable this reordering ?
About 3. See edit

Sublime Text 2 for example does this all very naturally.

**Edit**
I found out that I can drag a tab from one side to another, BUT I need to drag it a little bit down first so the tab gets "loose"

Comment: I can only suggest using "Show tabs in single row" in Settings | Editor | Editor Tabs -- never jumps for me.

Comment: I'm with you on this one. Drives me crazy. I think disabling this was overlooked since PhpStorm defaults to autoclosing tabs after you open a certain number. Both modes are equally confusing IMO and the reordering of rows is a feature that desperately needs the option to be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix yet, these are known issues:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22546
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84887

A workaround would be to use tabs on left/right or in single row options.

Comment: use left/right and disable **Alphabetical Mode**  
see my answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602453/how-do-i-stop-tabs-from-re-ordering-inside-jetbrains-intellij/17550591#17550591