# Intellij IDEA - new tabs not opening at the end despite setting

Tags: intellij-idea

On 2019.3.

Open new tab at end is checked, yet when I double click on a file that is not open, it is opening on the first position and thus rearranging my tabs.

Why?

I have tried with both tabs in one row and multiple rows. same result.

I think this has to do with the setting activate most recent on close. they are connected despite no reason for it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the video of the problem, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the exact steps. Also attach the logs: Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...

Comment: It seems to happen for a particular problem. I will try to catch it before it disappears.

Comment: Added ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233543?project=IDEA with video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a known issue:

- [IDEA-220087](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220087) "Open new tabs at the end" preference has no effect whatsoever

Comment: YouTrack search [works just fine](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20IDEA,IDEABKL%20new%20tab%20end).

Comment: yes, seems so... i've had it for years.. so definetly for longer than 6 months. – momomo 56 secs ago    Edit    Delete

Comment: I think the search returned one result. The others are burried within. Because closed? Why?

Comment: The [search query I've linked](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20IDEA,IDEABKL%20new%20tab%20end) provides [all the results including the closed duplicates](https://i.imgur.com/207nwVG.png).

Comment: I guess. My bad.

Comment: The oldest of those tickets is over 2 years old ... CrazyCoder, not sure you remember me, but seriosuly, Intellij needs to start focusing on actual IDEA usability. I've seen little progress since 2008. Focus instead has been on providing lots of new programming language support and features. But little actual usability features since then. Editor wise. I have so many ideas on how to improve things on how you work with tabs, but I have no time to actually implement those grandios ideas. A couple of plugins has been developed by us for most simple things, but more can and needs to be done.

Comment: I hope you can have such a discussion with the team on putting some focus on that.

Comment: Sure, feel free to report any ideas in YouTrack, we have the team handling and prioritizing such usability requests.